# discord.py scheduler to stop

Tags: discord, discord.py, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have this schedule tasks using apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio.AsyncIOScheduler when I say `-startc` the schedule starts. When I say `stopc` I want the schedule to stop.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startc(self, ctx):

    channel = ctx.channel.id
    self.client.scheduler.add_job(self.cardDrop, CronTrigger(second='0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50'), args=[channel])

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def stopc(self, ctx):
```

Comment: Can you please refine your question? What are you intending with "schedule" are you attempting to make a task loop?

Comment: yeah a task loop but using apescheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thank you for your help.

it was

```
self.client.scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)
```

False is if you want to stop the task immediately. True is when you want to wait till the task is complete and then stop

Answer (score 0):

Use `stop()`

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startc(self, ctx):

    channel = ctx.channel.id
    self.client.scheduler.add_job(self.cardDrop, CronTrigger(second='0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50'), args=[channel])

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def stopc(self, ctx):
    self.client.scheduler.stop()
```

Comment: I have other scheduled tasks. Not in this Cog, will those also get stopped?

Comment: AsyncIOScheduler doesnt have the attribute stop()